# delete duplicates

Tags: php, sql

Is it possible to delete just one column in a table when display out?

```
company name ||  name || year||
____________________________________
walmart      || jason || 1990
___________________________________
walmart      || mary  || 2000
```

to

```
company name ||  name || year||
____________________________________
walmart      || jason || 1990
___________________________________
             || mary  || 2000
____________________________________
```

the data is retrieved from database.

Comment: I suggest the title be edited; OP is not trying to delete anything. He is trying to suppress (or hide) the display of duplicate values when output. (Might also be worthwhile tagging as a report.)

Answer (score 6):

you'll have to do this on the client side.
something like
while CurrentValue == PreviousValue write empty string.

Comment: Yup, this is definitely a client side / presentation issue and does not belong into the database.

Comment: Your algorithm depends on the tuples being grouped by company name, which is not guaranteed (unless the SQL request used GROUP BY).

Comment: order is implied from the posters problem. if the rows aren't sorted you can't have such output.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this in SQL, but that's the wrong place to do do.
This is also a typical feature of reporting tools.